# Wordpress IF IS MOBILE without tablets

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now if mobile = true means the contant will shows on smartphones & tablets, I want mobile = smartphones only, I mean like this:

```html
<?php if (wp_is_mobile() === true) { ?>
Content for smartphones only
<?php } ?>


<?php if (wp_is_mobile() === false) { ?>
Content for tablets & PC only
<?php } ?>
```

Of course, I have to do that with code on function.php beacuse I cant edit all "If is mobile" code all over my theme & plugins.

Comment: The documentation claims it checks the user agent for *"Mobile, Android, Silk/, Kindle, BlackBerry, Opera Mini, OperaMobi"*, and one would think that wouldn't fire the function on tablets ?

Comment: But it seems it does include tablets, here's an answer -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114369/excluding-ipad-from-wp-is-mobile

Comment: @adeneo: Why would you think that wouldn't fire on tablets? If nothing else Silk was used exclusively by the Kindle Fire tablet line until the Fire Phone came around. However, virtually no one uses a Fire Phone, so for all intents and purposes Silk is still exclusively a tablet browser.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - It just seemed like the intent was to fire on mobile only, and I didn't think it would match the iPad at least, but it does as the iPad user agent contains "mobile" as well. Anyway, seems like a stupid idea from Automaticc to not create two functions, one for mobile and one for tablets, can't be that hard.

Comment: Actually, it is, since there's usually not a distinction made between phones and tablets when it comes to browsers. Chrome for Android, for example, is exactly the same application whether its on a phone or a tablet.

Comment: "Mobile" is an ever-increasingly useless designation anyways. I could be browsing your site on a high-res QHD+ laptop with a LTE card. Am I mobile? I certainly would want mobile optimizations so I'm not downloading megs of expensive data, but I'd want a full-size view of your site. Focus more on device resolution (CSS media queries/responsive design) and network (Network Information API, though unfortunately support is minimal at the moment).

Comment: `wp_is_mobile()` is a joke, totally unreliable and doesn't work in most cases. There is no way in php to know browser info, so there will never be a reliable way in Wordpress to handle this issue

Comment: When I say "tablets" I mean tablets sizes.. you know, its bigger than smartphones.
I want wp_is_mobile will be max-width: 640px